# What's a good UML reference and why?

Tags: language-agnostic, reference, uml

What I really wanted to ask was "What's **THE BEST** UML reference and why", but I didn't wanna upset SO with a "subjective blah blah" title.

So can any of you guys (in particular people who have read more than one) help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More than the abovementioned UML User guide, if you want a reference book then I would go for the The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual (2nd Edition) by the same authors. This is the book they wrote to serve as reference guide.

By the way, if what you are looking for is not a book but a quick cheat sheet or reference guide, you can also take a look at one of the [Top Seven UML CheatSheets](http://modeling-languages.com/blog/content/top-seven-uml-cheatsheets)

Comment: Good suggestions for reference on using UML, I use the UML Superstructure Specification from OMG as a reference for the standard.

Answer (score 3):

[UML Bible](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0764526049.html) is considered by many to be the ultimate reference - including a friend of mine who actually teaches UML.
For a good introduction, Fowler's [UML Distilled](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#uml) is great as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for Fowler.  Doesn't set out to be a reference per se - more of a tutorial / intro.  However I find I reach for it first every time when looking something up.  And it usually has the answer.  Really good book.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the [Unified Modeling Language User Guide, The (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321267974) for a complete reference, and it is written by some top dogs in the object modeling field. It is not set up as a tutorial with examples, et al, so it assumes you know reasonably well what you're doing and goes through and explains all of the fine details of the specification. It's also well-bound and well-formatted by the same people that produced the GoF's Design Patterns book. Highly recommended!

Comment: thanks for your recommendation :)

Answer (score 1):

I have many books (primarily on UML for embedded real-time systems, so possibly not relevant to you); none of which I would heartily recommend; the subject is too often treated very dryly.  I do however recommend you check that any you consider cover at least UML 2.x not UML 1.1.

Of all the resources I have used, the most useful have probably been the [free tutorials](http://sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/index.html) on the Sparx Systems' website.  It cannot hurt to take a look; it's hard to argue with free.  They have a number of other [resources](http://sparxsystems.com/resources/index.html) also that may be of interest, though some are somewhat EA specific.

Answer (score 0):

Object-oriented Systems analysis and design using UML

By Bennett

It is given as indicative reading on my degree course so may also be considered a text book. It has added to the initial understanding given to my by Fowler's UML Distilled.